# geom_ribbon is making export extremely slow

Tags: r, ggplot2

In R, I am plotting a large (400,000+ timepoints) timeseries with `ggplot`. It is two mean traces with each a `geom_ribbon` as error bar.

I am having serious problems exporting this plot in `png` in a decent amount of time. While trying a few different tweaks, I found that `geom_ribbon` was the main culprit.

Here is a reproducible example (it is not as bad as my real data for some reason, but good enough for my question).

**Create example data**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(tictoc)

test <- structure(list(grp = c("wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "ko", 
          "ko", "ko", "ko", "ko"), 
          sec = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 226151, 226152, 226153, 226154, 
                  226155), mean = c(11.5208333333333, 
         9.84020145833333, 12.3625, 12.2381927083333, 
         11.6596766666667, 17.1381563414634, 16.0591951219512, 
         14.7609756097561, 12.5528292682927, 0),
         sem = c(5.07322179860576, 4.04012867067194, 
         4.56616703891842, 4.70160041654607, 4.39606445058998, 
         3.02442054646122, 2.8947715702581, 2.73842770904548, 
         2.87276280525331, 0)), .Names = c("grp", "sec", "mean", 
         "sem"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
         row.names = c(NA, -10L))
nrows <- 400000
test2 <- do.call("rbind", replicate(nrows/10, test, 
         simplify = FALSE))
test2$sec[1:(nrow(test2)/2)] <- 1:(nrow(test2)/2)
test2$sec[(nrow(test2)/2+1):nrow(test2)] <- 1:(nrow(test2)/2)
```

**Plot with/without ribbon**

```
testp <- ggplot(test2, aes(x=sec, y=mean, group=grp, colour=grp)) +
  geom_line() + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=mean-sem, ymax=mean+sem, 
  fill=grp), alpha=0.4)

testp2 <- ggplot(test2, aes(x=sec, y=mean, group=grp, 
    colour=grp)) + geom_line()
```

**Export with/without ribbon**

```
tic('ribbon')
ggsave(filename='testp.png', device='png', plot=testp, dpi=20, 
        width=5, height=5, units='in')
toc()

tic('no ribbon')
ggsave(filename='testp2.png', device='png', plot=testp2, dpi=20, 
       width=5, height=5, units='in')
toc()
```

**Results**

```
 ribbon: 26.729 sec elapsed

 no ribbon: 2.009 sec elapsed
```

I do not understand why it takes so much longer with the ribbons. It also seems to increase exponentially with the number of rows, which is a real pain (2x more rows takes 5x longer with ribbon, while 2x longer without ribbon, as expected). This does not make sense to me!

What can I do about it?

Comment: Are you sure you actually *want* `geom_ribbon`? At 400,000+ timepoints, I fail to see how individual points matter for plotting purpose, unless your plot is as long as the wall of a building. Perhaps [`geom_smooth`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html) could suit your needs?

Comment: Ok, interesting idea! Would you mind detailling a bit how to reach a similar result though? Perhaps in answer so I can accept it. I am having trouble controlling the smoothing with the `gam` method (the default is definitely smoothing too much) and I am not sure how to go about reproducing the error ribbon...